# Hibernate - creating child object by updating parent but need generated key of child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

At my work, I am working on code that goes something like this...

Parent object is User, and child object is Profile. The way we create Profile is by doing something like user.addProfile(profile) and then service.update(user). So I am not directly creating a child object but since they have a relationship and cascading I believe that is how the child object gets created.

In this scenario, I need the key of the Profile that gets created, is this possible when updating the Parent object?

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to use a shared primary key or if you actually want to retrieve the key after persist.

Comment: I want to retrieve the key of the profile, it is one that will be generated after the persist. Right now I can only do this by using a method that saves the profile, and sets the user on the profile. However, I still need to update the User with important information, so I cant ignore that step.

Comment: As i understand from you question you need to retrieve the ID of profile after persisting it? Why dont you try `user.getProfile().getKey()`?

Comment: The problem is the user will have multiple profiles, so I need the one that gets created. I should have mentioned that. But your understanding is correct. Currently I update the user, THEN save the profile, so from the success I return profile.getProfileKey(), instead of user.getUserKey(). I don't like having 2 service calls from 1 rest call, I am not sure if that is bad design or not but doesn't sound good, so I would like to just update the User and retrieve the newly created Child key

Comment: Then the maping could be wrong. If the user has multiple profiles you should be doing user.addProfile(profile) so, one to many list. once you save it to the db the profile object will now have a id assigned to it which you can use

Comment: Maybe I worded badly, I need the key as soon as it gets created, I already know the key is being created. Everything is working fine no errors, the issue is that I need the key of the profile that gets created. It gets created when updating the user through a service call to the dao. I get the user key when update is successful, I need the profile key instead, but how? calling user.getprofilekey wont work because profiles is a set, I need the one that was just persisted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is when the bi-directional mapping helps. Create a User property in the Profile entity. Instead of saving the `User` entity save the `Profile` entity.

**eg:**

```
profile.setUser(user)
session.saveOrUpdate(profile)

profile.getkey()//this will have the key and it can be used immediately
```

**Update:**

```
Profile p = ... //somehow created this
User u = session.get(id,User.class);
u.addProfile(p);
session.saveOrUpdate(u);

p = getLastCreatedChild(u.getProfiles());  // based on the time it is created/ sorted by id you can get the last created child here
p.getKey();// will have the id


-------------User.java------------------

public class User {

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<Profile> profiles;
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, however this is already what I am doing as I addressed in the comments. The problem is the user has a set of profiles, which is modified when creating a new profile. I must go through that list of profiles, make changes, and save the list of profiles. On top of all that, I need to get the key of the new created profile, so in my case I am making 2 service calls: 1 for update user(and profiles), another 1 for service.saveProfile(profile) to get the profile key. All I need to know is it its possible to get a key from child object created from updating the parent object

Comment: @CatznDogz If you save the parent object the child objects will be saved(with proper cascade options like orphanRemoval) automatically/updated. After saving get the last child in the list based on time created by looping through the list. Yes, this last child will have the id assigned to it which you want